# How to calculate position from accelerometer x y z values in phonegap

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

I am using phonegap AccelListener to get accelerometer readings . My code is as follows :

```
var acc = [];
var watchId;
function startWatch() {

        var options = { frequency: 3000 };

        watchID = navigator.accelerometer.watchAcceleration(onSuccess,onError, options);
    }

    function stopWatch () {

        if (watchID) {
            navigator.accelerometer.clearWatch(watchID);
            watchID = null;
        }

    }

function onSuccess(acceleration) {
    console.log(acceleration);

        var element = 'Acceleration X: ' + acceleration.x         + '<br />' +
                            'Acceleration Y: ' + acceleration.y         + '<br />' +
                            'Acceleration Z: ' + acceleration.z         + '<br />' +
                            'Timestamp: '      + acceleration.timestamp + '<br />';
    console.log(element);
    acc.push(element);
    }
function onError() {
        alert('onError!');
    }
```

This will give me x y z values for every 3 seconds. I know that accelerometer values are used to find out device motion . But is there any way to calculate position from these values. Any help??

Comment: what exactly do you mean by position?

Comment: location , longitude latitude in map

Comment: That's not possible. These values give you the angle of how the phone is being held. You're searching for [this](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/edge/cordova_geolocation_geolocation.md.html#geolocation.getCurrentPosition).

Comment: ok . I tried with geoLocation whatever link u have given but that will not work offline. Anyway thanks . Some people say if we do double integration of acceleration we can get position . But i dont know how to do that .

Comment: You don't need internet connection for the geolocation plugin, only the GPS function must be enabled

Comment: To do this with double integration, you would have to know the position and velocity at some point in time.  Just a whole load of measurements of acceleration won't solve it for you.

Comment: ok can u guide me how to do that with some sample values?

Answer (score -1):

As can be read in the cordova documentation [here](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/edge/cordova_accelerometer_accelerometer.md.html#Accelerometer), "the accelerometer is a motion sensor that detects the change (delta) in movement relative to the current device orientation, in three dimensions along the x, y, and z axis." So the accelerometer gives you the angle of how the phone is held by the user.

To get the current position you can use the [Geolocation](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/edge/cordova_geolocation_geolocation.md.html#Geolocation) plugin provided by cordova.

Comment: ok . I tried with geoLocation whatever link u have given but that will not work offline. Anyway thanks . Some people say if we do double integration of acceleration we can get position . But i dont know how to do that .